# Add CSS-class to current node in module logic

Tags: theming

In a custom module, I add some logic to the node rendering. Based on this, I would also like to add some appropriate CSS-classes to the current node.
The below code expresses  what I would like to do, but don't know how to do.

```
$node->classes[] = $class;
```

Because I already have the appropriate logic in my module, it seems to me like the adding of classes should be handled in the same place. I could do this in a template instead, but that would require me to duplicate all the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [hook_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_process_HOOK/7) help you for this?

Example:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'blah';
}
```

The variables array contains all information about the ndoe as well, so you can run logic to dictate which classes should be added to which node types/IDs etc.

If you run dpm (with the [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module enabled) then you can print everything in that array that you can alter/add to.

I agree that `$node->classes` would be a really useful addition though.

Comment: Perhaps it's the only way to do what I want, but this does still come with the issue that my logic needs to be duplicated into two functions.